# How to make a field Mandatory in Windows Installer custom dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, setup-project, orca

I've recently created a setup project for my C# .NET Windows Forms Application.

In my User Interface Editor I have:

```
- Start
  - Welcome
  - Textboxes (A)
  - Installation Folder
  - Confirm Installation
```

In the **Textboxes (A) dialog** I have one edit field that I want to make mandatory.

How can I do that?  I've downloaded the **Orca** editor.  Is there a simple way to use that to do that?

These are the two goals I hope to achieve *(goal 1 at least)*:

1. To enable/disable the next button based on edit label being non-empty
2. Is it possible to validate the contents after hitting the next button?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Installer Dialog definitions are located in `CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin\VsdDialogs` folder under the IDE folder of the deployed version of VS, for example for a VS 2017 it is something like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin\VsdDialogs\
```

In that folder, go to `0` and `1033` folders, run [`orca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) as administrator and change the `VsdCustomText1Dlg.wid` file which is for `Textboxes (A)`.

> **Note 1**: You can create a new windows installer dialog by copying that
> file and renaming it to `MyCustomDialog.wid`. Then open it in orca and
> go to `ModuleDialog` table and change the `DisplayName` to `My Custom Dialog`. Make sure you copy the file in both `1033` and `0`. Then in
> VS, you can add an instance of this dialog using User Interface Editor
> of Setup project.

> **Note 2**: You can also edit the `msi` file using `Orca` and edit the control conditions, but if you do so, then every time you build the setup project, you need to repeat editing of the `msi` file. So editing `.wid` makes more sense.

> **Note 3**: Combining conditions of fields using `AND` and `OR` is possible as well. For more information, take a look at
> [ControlCondition
> Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/controlcondition-table?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
> and [Conditional Statement
> Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/conditional-statement-syntax?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

### Make a field mandatory in Windows Installer custom dialog

To make the `Edit1` value mandatory and enable or disable <kbd>Next</kbd> button:

1. Run `orca` as administrator
2. Open the `wid` file which you used for adding the custom dialog.
3. In `ControlCondition`, in addition to existing rows add the following rows:

   ```
    ┌──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
    │ Dialog_      │ Control_     │ Action       │ Condition    │
    ├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────┤
                                 ...
    │ CustomTextA  │ NextButton   │ Disable      │ EDITA1=""    │
    │ CustomTextA  │ NextButton   │ Enable       │ EDITA1<>""   │
    └──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
   ```
4. Save the file and make sure you have the same file in both `1033` and `0` folders.
5. Close `Orca`
6. Rebuild setup project.
7. Install it.

As a result you will see such behavior:

[image]

Comment: Hi can I get the edited `wid` file and the setup project so that I can use it.

Comment: I have saved as a new one but couldn't get it working. I copied to all the folder where wid files exists. I am using VS2019

Comment: Can we have OR and AND condition to make multiple controls mandatory?

Comment: You just need to edit the `.wid` file and use it when creating the setup. You don't need to edit the `.msi` file, If you edit the setup file, then every time that you build the setup project, you need to repeat editing the setup file. So editing `.wid` makes more sense.

Comment: `AND` and `OR` is possible. For more information, take a look at [ControlCondition Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/controlcondition-table?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [Conditional Statement Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/conditional-statement-syntax?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)